# Vagrant GuestAdditions issue

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

- Host OS: Windows 10
- Vagrant: 2.2.4
- VirtualBox: 6.0.6 r130049

When I run `vagrant up`, it prints this error message:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

 setup

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

bash: line 4: setup: command not found
```

The machine can be booted normally and SSH from my host to Virtual machine is OK but the synced folder is not working. I know this may not be a critical issue but still feel frustrated as I use my host machine to develop codes and "sync" these codes so that they can be loaded in my virtual machine.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

ps: When I boot a full UI virtual machine (different from my above mentioned) from my VirtualBox directly, it seems OK to have a "sync" directory and the VBGuestAdditions can be installed without errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18598) in VirtualBox 6.0.6 and it still exists in 6.0.8. The solution is to downgrade your VirtualBox itself and the Guest Extensions to 6.0.4.